# ipywidgets not displaying while jupyter-js-widgets/extension is enabled

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

ipywidgets is not displaying IntSlider. I checked that my jupyter-js-widgets/extension is enabled. I tried several different browsers as well but didn't help.

Here is the code:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
w = widgets.IntSlider()
display(w)
```

And output is just like so without a slider:

```
IntSlider(value=0)
```